# How to define a function returning a cpp-defined type in Cython?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython

## Overview of the problem

I'll be as brief as possible.

Suppose I have a class `Bar`, defined in `./cpp/Bar.h` and implemented in `./cpp/Bar.cpp`.
Then, I have another class, `Foo`, defined in `./cpp/Foo.h` and implemented in `./cpp/Foo.cpp`.
One of the methods in `Foo` returns a pointer to `Bar`, that is:

```
Bar* fubar()
    {
        Bar* value;
        /*irrelevant computation*/
        return value;
    }
```

[Following the cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html), I have ported these two classes to as follows.

- *`./Foo.pxd`*

```
cdef extern from "./cpp/Foo.cpp" namespace "Baz":
    pass

cdef extern from "./cpp/Foo.h" namespace "Baz":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo() except +
        Bar fubar() ## ERROR: Bar is not a type identifier
```

- *`./PyFoo.pyx`*

```
from Foo cimport Foo

from PyBar import PyBar

cdef class PyFoo:
    cdef Foo c_foo

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_foo = Foo()

    def fubar(self) -> PyBar:
        return self.c_foo.fubar()
```

- *`./Bar.pxd`*

```
cdef extern from "./cpp/Bar.cpp" namespace "Baz":
    pass

cdef extern from "./cpp/Bar.h" namespace "Baz":
    cdef cppclass Bar:
        Bar() except +
```

- *`./PyBar.pyx`*

```
from Bar cimport Bar

cdef class PyBar:
    cdef Bar c_bar

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_bar = Bar()
```

During the compilation, when it gets to `./PyFoo.pyx`, I get notified that '*Bar is not a type identifier*'.

## Desired behaviour

A successfully compiling Cython module, with `PyFoo.fubar()` returning an instance of `PyBar`.

## What have I tried

- the only help online I found for adding Cpp types is for template classes
- adding these lines to `./Foo.pxd`

  ```
  cdef extern from "./cpp/Bar.h" namespace "Baz":
      pass
  ```

  to expose the desired header file to this file did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is not the C++ headers, but Cython knowing of the existence of the types. You do this through `cimport`ing pxd files.

Foo.pxd becomes:

```
cimport Bar

cdef extern from "./cpp/Foo.h" namespace "Baz":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo() except +
        Bar.Bar fubar()
```

Note that I've also removed the textual inclusion of the C++ file. Remove this from Bar.pxd too. I'd suggest adding that to the ["sources" list in your setup.py file](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build) instead.

Comment: This, indeed, solves the issue. The cimporting should be covered in broader way in the tutorial than it is now.
Thank you!